# Why is timeit.timeit slow

Tags: python

I did following experiment:

```
>>> L = [2 ** n for n in range(10)]
# This returns immediately
>>> exec('L = [2 ** n for n in range(10)]')
# This returns immediately as well
>>> timeit.timeit('L = [2 ** n for n in range(10)]')
2.202632000000449

~$ time python -c 'L = [2 ** n for n in range(10)]'
real    0m0.047s
user    0m0.031s
sys     0m0.016s
```

Why did timeit take more than 2 seconds ? Is there a way to improve it ?

Comment: Use `timeit.timeit('L = [2 ** n for n in range(10)]',number=1)`

Comment: As [stated in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/timeit.html#timeit.timeit) by default `number= 1000000` so your code is run 1,000,000 times

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is answered directly by the documentation and does not require human intervention to produce a comprehensive answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because documentation answers the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.timeit):

> #### `timeit.timeit(stmt='pass', setup='pass', timer=<default timer>, number=1000000, globals=None)`
>
> Create a [`Timer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer) instance with the given statement, *setup* code and *timer* function and run its [`timeit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.timeit) method with *number* executions. The optional *globals* argument specifies a namespace in which to execute the code.

The [`Timer.timeit()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.timeit) on the other hand is explained like this:

> #### `timeit(number=1000000)`
>
> Time *number* executions of the main statement. This executes the setup statement once, and then returns the time it takes to execute the main statement a number of times, measured in seconds as a float. The argument is the number of times through the loop, defaulting to one million. The main statement, the setup statement and the timer function to be used are passed to the constructor.

So why is `timeit.timeit` slow? Because it runs the passed statement *a million times* by default. This is so that it can benchmark the statement by running it over and over until you can safely deduce how performant the statement is. This is a [common thing to do](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) so that you can average out outliers.

Answer (score 4):

Because [`timeit.timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.timeit) executes the code snippet one million times in order to calculate proper statistics on how long the code snippet takes to execute.

You can use the `number` keyword argument to change the number of repetitions:

```
timeit.timeit('L = [2 ** n for n in range(10)]', number=100)
```

Answer (score 1):

timeit try to execute the code snippets a lot of time, and give in output an avarege result.